# I can't change variable from function on event listener in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a window `mousemove` event listener, that calls a function that changes a variable. However when I assign the varibale to a prop it doesn't change:

```
  var x = null
  var y = null

  const cursor = (e) => {
    x = e.screenX + 'px'
    y = e.screenY + 'px'
    console.log(x, y)
    return x, y
  }

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor)
```

I tried to directly change it in the event listener

(`window.addEventListener('mousemove', //everything in cursor`) but then I wouldn't be able to access the `e` variable.

I also can't use it with state because for some reason it's gets too laggy and crashes.

How can I make this work? Thanks in advance.

That's what I see in vscode:

[image]

(This is in the App component, the variables and the evenet listener are in the App too.)

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-agnesi-9l1ic?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: console.log() is printing co-ordinates. it's working

Comment: Added a sandbox

Comment: Sandbox appears to be the default initial react template. Did you save your edits?

Comment: Try it now, it should work

Comment: Components only re-render when state or props update. `App` has no state, or props so it never re-renders, this the child `Cursor` never re-renders. Add `.attrs(props => {
  console.log('props', props)
  return {};
})` to `Cursor` to see one log.

Comment: @Vaibhav yeah i know but I can't access it **outside** the function

Comment: You can declare `x,y` variables in index.html and access them globally, but be cautious it can be antipattern if mess with React state.

Comment: You dont have any state variables there. If any state's value or props's value changes then only react will rerender components. In your case x & y are just variables. If you make them as state variables then it will rerender again.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: https://pastebin.com/zG4JcmMj (i have an issue with codesandbox)

Comment: I created using state & it is working fine as expected.. But the problem is whenever we change cursor position it is triggering component rerender lot of times. I even tried to use context api but it doesnt rerender...

Comment: I think its better to write window.addEventListener in directly in your child component rather passing from parent component

Comment: @Roy So, the only problem is you cannot use the modified `x` and `y` variables you've declared on the first two lines, right?

Comment: Yep (more text so i can reach the chars limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Components only re-render when state or props update. `App` has no state, or props so it never re-renders, thus the child `Cursor` never re-renders.

You can use a ref attached to `Cursor` and set the top and left properties directly. Please don't forget to also remove the event listener when the component unmounts.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Cursor = styled.div`
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
`;

export default function App() {
  const posRef = useRef(null);

  const cursor = e => {
    const { clientX = 0, clientY = 0 } = e;

    posRef.current.style.left = clientX + "px";
    posRef.current.style.top = clientY + "px";

    // console.log(clientX, clientY);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", cursor);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", cursor);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <Cursor ref={posRef} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit custom cursor]

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @KirillSkomarovskiy, using state wasn't what was bogging down and crashing the page. I suspect it is/was the adding of multiple/duplicate `mousemove` handlers that weren't being cleaned up properly (*possibly compounded by logging each updated position*).

```
const Cursor = styled.div`
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: ${props => props.yPos};
  left: ${props => props.xPos};
`;

export default function App() {
  const [pos, setPos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const cursor = e => {
      setPos({
        x: e.clientX + "px",
        y: e.clientY + "px"
      });
      // console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    };
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", cursor);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("mousemove", cursor);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Demo</h1>
      <Cursor xPos={pos.x} yPos={pos.y} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cursor demo]

Comment: Why do you use `useRef` instead of `useState`?

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Namely that, as the PO points out, tracking all the mousemove events **and** trying to update a component's state overwhelms the javascript thread, and it's even worse when you throw in the console.log of each event. Using `useState` had very poor performance. Since the component isn't really "rendering" anything it's more of a container. The ref allows access to the underlying DOM node and we're just updating the position of a "cursor" div.

Comment: @DrewReese I've compared `useRef` and `useState` and haven't noticed any performance difference. [here](https://hfzpl.csb.app) is my example.

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy Wow, you're absolutely right. I went back and reimplemented it from the OP's sandbox using state and I think what was happening to me previously is I hadn't made the other optimizations to remove listeners (multiple listeners running) *and* still console logging the coords. https://2jqov.csb.app/

Answer (score -1):

The variables `x` and `y` will never effectively be updated because `cursor()` is an ES6 arrow function which works in a `functional` way, so if you want to pass values from `cursor()` to `x` or `y`, then you should consider them as functions as well:

```
x = (callback) =>{
   return callback;
}

y = (callback) =>{
   return callback;
}
```

Now you can pass values to `x` and `y`:

```
const cursor = (e) => {
    x (e.screenX + 'px');
    y (e.screenY + 'px');
}
```

Then your Event Listener calls `cursor(e)`:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);
```

Wherever you want to use the values of `x` and `y` you just need to call them like: `x()` or `y()`.

This is how `ES6 Functional Programming` works!